# Wedding invitation card riddle

Tags: riddle, puzzle-creation

I'm looking for a riddle to put on my wedding invitation card. Ideally it's short (3 lines max) and not english-specific, as my guests are arabic - speakers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a desired solution/subject matter?

Comment: Not really, but it'd be nice if it were related to the wedding.

Comment: (Not related to the question, but...) Congratulations on getting married!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

> We are a symbol of unity, of love that's bloomed
>   Up the aisle, through the room
>   There's two of us, but we're not bride or groom
>   
>   What am I?

To which the answer would be

> A wedding ring
>
> Unites two people who have fallen in love
> Brought up the aisle as everyone watches the ceremony
> Two rings, one for bride one for groom, yet they aren't either

To save you the trouble here it is in arabic:

> نحن رمزا للوحدة، من الحب الذي هو أزهرت
>   حتى في الممر، من خلال غرفة
>   هناك اثنين منا، لكننا لا العروس أو العريس
>
> ما أنا؟

Quite nice as it rhymes as well as being related to a wedding, and is 3 lines long (excluding the 'What am I?')

Comment: I see great minds think alike here! :)

Comment: Thank you for the riddle and the initiative of translating it nicely into arabic :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an adaptation of a riddle I discovered online [here](http://www.justriddlesandmore.com/Solved/riddlessolvedfour.html):

True love's quest will end with me
Yet I am crafted endlessly
I'm seen on hands and feet and heads
And every hour my name is said
**What am I?**

Answer:

> I am a **ring**.
>
>  Wedding rings are used to symbolize and finalize marriage;
>  Yet a ring has no end in its shape;
>  They are worn on toes, fingers, and ears (as well as other places on the face and body);
>  And every hour, the church bell rings to indicate the time.

Comment: Same answer as mine :) Just a note: '3 lines max'

Comment: Well, you could combine lines 1&2 and lines 3&4 very easily. I separated them just for clarity. :)

Comment: Thank you for your riddle. There is no "right" or "wrong" answer to my post, so I just chose the answer I got chronologically first. :)